# category description in footer in 1.9.2.0 / 1.9.2.0.1

Tags: category, cache, footer, block-cache

I have a line in

/template/page/html/footer.phtml

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription(); ?>
```

Now with BLOCK_HTML Cache enabled, the footer repeats only the first hit of a description text.

Is that the same bug as with the cms/block caching thing?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, the footer block is always cached by Magento, if you put dynamic content here it will be cached and you will only see the first cached version.

If you want to disable caching of the footer you will need to extend

```
app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Footer.php
```

and comment out the cache commands in the class construct.

I would recommend you put this content in a custom block above the footer that will not be cached.